# Free software to convert MTS file to MP4

Tags: windows, gratis, video, media-converter, mp4

I want to convert a 150MB `.MTS` video file into `.MP4` video format file.

I tried [Any Video Converter](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/), but that did not work.

Does anyone know of a free Windows 7 converter?

Comment: There are [dozens of programs that claim to do that](https://www.google.com/search?q=mts+to+mp4). Trying a few out is faster than waiting for an answer here. If you find a nice one you can even answer your own question.

Comment: did you tried total video converter?

Comment: I tried out numerous ones (including Total video converter), all free ones that I tried had some limitations in one or the other form, like "watermark","can convert to only 10 or 20 mb max".Since nothing helped, I am willing to wait here :)

Comment: try VLC (aka videolan client)  On the surface it seems to only  be a player, but it isn't.  Under the **media** menu there is a **convert and save** option or CTRL R.

Answer (score 1):

[Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) might be another option to consider. It can take a lot of different formats (including MTS) and convert it to MP4 or MKV.
And from what I've expirienced, it scales great across multiple cores.

Answer (score -1):

You can try format factory, it's a really good in convert things:

http://www.pcfreetime.com/?language=pt

Comment: Format Factory installs unwanted or malware programs.